# How do I find the nth row from a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in which data is something like this:

```
Name    Salary
Tom      10000
John     20000
Ram      20000
Danny    15000
Sandy    14000
Riddle   15000
```

I can find 2nd highest salary using `cte`;

```
with cte
as
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Salary desc) as r,
    * from Employee e
)
select * from cte where r=2
```

But this gives the result 'Ram' with 20000 salary. What I would like returned is every record for people with the nth-ranking salary. For instance, if I'm looking for `n=2`, the result would be:

```
Danny    15000
Riddle   15000
```

How do I modify the query to achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried varying the value of `r` you're testing? ie `select * from cte where r=4` or `r=7`? Or, indeed, `r = n`?

Comment: @Nathaniel -i tried and n in (3,4) give me result but in real scenario, how i can find the people with 2nd highest salary ??

Comment: its ms sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Are you saying you want the people with the nth highest salary (e.g. 3rd highest salary is (14000)), or you want the person who is the nth highest in salary? Very different questions.

Comment: @marc_s The specific database system and version is not important to this question. This is a basic sql question. I agree with McKay; this questions is not well asked. Who is in the nth position or what people have the salary in the nth position?

Comment: @nathaniel-ford - question is simple, see my desired result i give clean indication that i need two records with 15000 salary and i believe here two records mean people not person

Comment: @Arun I hate to say it, but your last two sentences are ambiguous. "A different record" suggests a singular result being returned. "Danny *and* Riddle" suggests multiple records. This is not a 'clean indication', but I'm happy that people were able to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`DENSE_RANK()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS r, *
    FROM Employee e
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE r = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/927e6/1)

Comment: @Ic. can't we do this without DENSE_Rank ? using partition can help ?

Comment: @Arun What do you mean? DENSE_RANK would be the best tool for the job here. You can simulate it with a row number over a distinct query, but I don't see the point

Comment: @Ip as per my understanding, DENSE_RANK is applied on partition not on Rows as ROW_NUMBER did am i correct?

Comment: It's basically the same as ROW_NUMBER, but instead assigns each duplicate value the same sequence number. Think a top 100 chart.

Answer (score 2):

I posted about this on my blog:
https://fullparam.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/sql-select-nth-rank-of-something-three-approaches/

Correlated subquery:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, BaseRate
FROM DimEmployee e
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT BaseRate)
    FROM DimEmployee p WHERE e.BaseRate=p.BaseRate) = 4
```

Why is this a good answer? It’s not really but this will work on any SQL implementation.
It’s fairly slow, it will do a lot of look ups.  The subquery is evaluated every time a row is processed by the outer query. This query uses dense ranking and can return multiple rows.

Double Order By with TOP statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FirstName, LastName, BaseRate
FROM ( SELECT TOP 4 FirstName, LastName, BaseRate
    FROM DimEmployee ORDER BY BaseRate DESC) AS MyTable
ORDER BY BaseRate ASC;
```

Why is this a good answer? Because it is an easy syntax to remember.
Let’s look at the subquery, which returns the N highest salaries in the DimEmployee table in descending order. Then, the outer query will re-order those values in ascending (default) order, this means the Nth highest salary will now be the topmost salary. Keep in mind that the TOP statement is MS SQL server specific. MySQL would use LIMIT 1 for instance. In addition this solution cannot do DENSE ranking and only returns one row even if two employees share the same BaseRate.

Use Windowing function:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, BaseRate
FROM (SELECT FirstName, LastName, BaseRate, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BaseRate DESC) Ranking
FROM DimEmployee) AS MyTable
WHERE Ranking = 4
```

Why is this a good answer? Because it performs the best – performance is king. The Syntax is also ANSI SQL however of the “Big 3” only Oracle and MS are using it. In addition you can chose to use ROW_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK or regular RANK.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
WITH
cte AS
(select DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY Salary desc) AS R, e.*
from Employee e)
SELECT * From cte
WHERE R =2
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a0d1/18)

Comment: No offense, but how is this any different from my answer?

Comment: When I opened the question there were no answers, and suddenly when I posted, yours was 8 minutes before, but didn't appear in my page

Comment: Odd. Fair enough. Just was wondering if you intended to do something differently.

Answer (score 1):

u can get the 2nd highest salary by using CO-RELATED Query as follows:

```
select name from employee e1   --outer query

   where 2= --2nd highest salary

(select COUNT(e2.salary)       --inner query

from employee e2 where e2.salary >= e1.salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` keyword might help you here.

```
SELECT Salary FROM Employee order by Salary desc
```

will return

```
20000
20000
15000
15000
14000
10000
```

but add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee order by Salary desc
```

will return

```
20000
15000
14000
10000
```

So which do you want, the third highest person by salary (which isn't guaranteed to always be the same, as two people might share the 15,000 salary), or the people who have the third highest salary (which in this case, is only one person who has the 14,000 salary, but that's no guarantee.

Comment: @Arun Sir, I don't think you understand my answer. I'll admit it isn't a complete answer, but rather a deeper question about concepts you need to keep straight.